# Set the orientation of screen in android

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am developing an application in which I have to change the screen orientation accordingly. This is my image.[image]

When my android device is vertical then this view of screen is fine. But when I rotate my screen to horizontal mode then my image should set above and the remaining components like Start, End and checkboxes must set below the image. Means layer type. In one layer which is first, there must be an image and in the second layer remaining components must set in horizontal mode.
How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: When ever you Edit/Update any Section , please use "Edit Section , Update Section" before it , it is good for all users to read and understand .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have different layouts for portrait and landscape you have to add a new folder in `"res"` called `"layout-land"`. There you have to put your xml-Layout-File for landscape mode. Name it exactly like the counterpart one in `"layout"`-Folder. Now Android automatically loads the right xml when the phone is turned.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity :

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: I have two activities. .MainActivity and .Fragement. I have added the solution in manifest but they are set as it is. Means Images above and components are under it. But they are not rotating. Means they are still in vertical manner

Comment: `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` disables the landscape mode for the Activity completely. That wasn't the question.

Comment: see my second image. I want exactly that when I rotate screen.

Comment: Create two layouts , one for landscape mode and another for vertical mode .

Comment: I think you are using Linear layout ! if yes , then convert it into Relative layout .

Answer (score 0):

Create new folder /res/layout-land It will help to change the layout after rotation.

Or if you want to save the rotation programatically add this function into your code:

```
 private void mLockScreenRotation()
        {
          // Stop the screen orientation changing during an event
            switch (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation)
            {
          case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            this.setRequestedOrientation(
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            break;
          case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            this.setRequestedOrientation(
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            break;
            }
        }
```

This is much better than

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: I have two activities. .MainActivity and .Fragement. I have added the solution in manifest but they are set as it is. Means Images above and components are under it. But they are not rotating. Means they are still in vertical manner

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.yourActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: I have two activities. .MainActivity and .Fragement. I have added the solution in manifest but they are set as it is. Means Images above and components are under it. But they are not rotating. Means they are still in vertical manner.